# Stop prompting for password every time I do something requiring privileges

Tags: root, users

I didn't see this answered satisfactorily anywhere, so I figured I'd ask.

Every time I go to do something requiring privileges, such as install a program, open restricted folders, etc., I'm prompted for the account password, even though my user account is an administrator.

How do I get it to stop prompting me for my password when doing such actions?

Comment: That is the way it is designed to work. If you need a root shell run `sudo -i` . You should not always need to run a root, only when you update, install software, or edit system files. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: Doing this will likely ruin the security of your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dirty workaround would be to set your account to not prompt for sudo passwords, but that is not recommended for security purposes.  if you type "sudo visudo"  you should be able to add an entry for your user that looks like this:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL    
username    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This may or may not work for the GUI as well

Comment: I'll stress again that I do not recommend this solution for any production environment or secure system.

Comment: Is there a way that can extend the password-ask interval to like 30 minutes or something?

Comment: adding `timestamp_timeout=(time in minutes)` to your sudoers file (either in defaults or in a specific rule section) might be what you are looking for

Comment: Worked Thanks :)